# Connection string environment variable not in Configuration object but can be found using GetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I am trying to use a configuration object instead of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable.

It is working fine except for the "SQLAZURECONNSTR_COMPANY" environment variable which can be accessed with GetEnvironmentVariable but does not show up in the Configuration.

I have this code in the main method of Program.cs

```
CreateWebHostBuilder(args).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom
                    .Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
            })
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build()
            .Run();
```

And to make sure all of my environment variables are set I am running this code in startup.cs

```
    var environmentVariableNames = new List<string>
            {
                "APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_KEY",
                "SQLAZURECONNSTR_COMPANY",
                "IDENTITY_API_BASE_URL"
            };

        foreach (var environmentVariableName in environmentVariableNames)
        {
            var x = Configuration[environmentVariableName];

            var environmentVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(environmentVariableName);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentVariable))
            {
                Log.Logger.Fatal($"Test.Company::ConfigureServices -  The {environmentVariableName} environment variable is null.  Please set the environment variable.  Application Stopping.");
                ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
            }
        }
```

For one of my environment variables, which I have set in the Project settings for local use, the expected value comes back from GetEnvironmentVariable but it is not in the Configuration object. All of my other environment variables are working as expected in the Configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the name of my environment variable. It was named "SQLAZURECONNSTR_COMPANY" which is fine to get with Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable but the configuration gets it and renames it to ConnectionStrings:COMPANY. The correct way for me to access this would be to call

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("COMPANY");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-connection-strings